# Подключение стороннего PHP файла и обход .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, https, xampp

Имеется VDS, серверные файлы онлайн игры, сайт.

Для логина в игру необходимо подключать апачи, использую xampp, на нём же стоит и сайт. Вчера ставил сайт, подключал SSL сертификат для сайта и настраивал переадресацию на HTTPS через .htaccess.

Столкнулся со следующими проблемами:

1) После подключения сайта перестал работать логин в игру. Проблема заключается в том, что изначально в настроенном xampp находился файл index.php (он сохранился), в котором был прописан следующий код:

```
$myFile = "log_post.txt"; 
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file"); 
fwrite($fh, "\n"); 
$headers = apache_request_headers(); 
foreach ($headers as $h => $v)
fwrite($fh, "$h: $v\n");
fwrite($fh, print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,1));
fclose($fh);
require('../lib/Framework/SiteHandler.php');
?>
```

После того, как я добавил HTML код в этот файл - логин перестал работать.
Убираю всё лишнее и оставляю только этот код (выше) - всё прекрасно работает.

Пытался подключить его отдельным файлом, писал include connect.php (в файле connect прописан тот же самый код, что я представил выше), однако это не помогает

Comment: отдельные вопросы задавайте, пожалуйста, отдельными вопросами.

Comment: Логи апача смотрели?